# Permission to publish online in power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a problem when I try to publish a report on web. A message saying that I need the permission of my admin to create the embed codes. 
And when I go to admin portal, there is error message

[embed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piJuo.png)

[admin portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3qFZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of February 2020, using the 'publish to web' function setting has changed, and is turned off by default, and can only be activated by the O365 admin or a defined Power BI Admin user. Under a normal Pro/Free user setting you don't get admin rights, or see the full admin portal.

More details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web)